# this keyword and functions like onClick block the code coverage

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to test the component below with Jest and Enzyme. Everything seems to work fine, I don't get any errors but for some reason, the code coverage does not go beyond the line onChange={(value) => { this.searchCallback(value)}}. When I comment on that line, the code coverage goes beyond that line and stops at window.open('https://somurl');. I also have other components and face the same issue when I test the other components. It seems like 'this' keyword or functions like onClick(), onClose() are blocking the code coverage. I did not see anything similar. I tried to test with shallow and mount but I run into the same issue in both cases.

```
  getTabContent(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <div className="page-header-items">
        <Input
          value={this.state.searchValue}
          type="search"
          placeholder={'Search'}
          icon="search"
          iconPosition="right"
          onChange={(value) => {
            this.searchCallback(value);
          }}
        />
        <Button
          type="primary"
          content={'Add'}
          onClick={() => {
            window.open('https://somurl');
          }}
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Code coverage is a functions which can be tested. Your onClick and onChange function can't be tested because it haven't any name. You should move it in some other place and then test it separately

Comment: I am not trying to test the onClick function. When I render this component in the test, everything stops after the onChange function.

Comment: If I correctly understand your post, you tell about code coverage. How code can be covered if it untested?